# Re-format scraped date in R

Tags: regex, r, date

I have scraped HTML and now I have rows like this:

```
                               rows
1: for the Year Ended 31 March 2013
```

I would like to extract only the expression `"31 March 2013"`. The text around the expression could vary. The expression is to be turned into date format, preferably `31-3-2013`

How to go about this?

Comment: Is the date always the three last words? Could there be other numerics or can you use a regex that gives you the two numerics and the word in between?

Comment: The thing is I don't know yet until I do the scrapping for all files. But including the possibility that it would not be last 3 words, would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no other numbers in your strings, you can use the following approach:

```
string <- "for the Year Ended 31 March 2013"

format(as.Date(sub(".*?(\\d+ \\w+ \\d+).*", "\\1", string), 
               "%d %B %Y"), "%d-%m-%Y")
# [1] "31-03-2013"
```

Here `sub` extracts the relevant substring, `as.Date` creates a object representing `Date` values, and `format` changes the order of the date elements.

---

It also works with additional text and one-digit days:

```
string <- c("for the Year Ended 31 March 2013",
            "1 January 2013 the Year Began",
            "for the Year Ended 31 March 2013 and not now")
format(as.Date(sub(".*?(\\d+ \\w+ \\d+).*", "\\1", string),
       "%d %b %Y"), "%d-%m-%Y")
# [1] "31-03-2013" "01-01-2013" "31-03-2013"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option :

```
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
dmy(str_extract(xx,'[0-9]{2}.*[0-9]{4}$'))
[1] "2013-03-31 UTC"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rows <- c("for the Year Ended 31 March 2013 ... 31 March 2013 ...",
          "for the Year Ended 1 December 2011")
m <- gregexpr("[0-9]+ [A-z]+ [0-9]{4}", rows)
# Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "english")
(res <- lapply(regmatches(rows, m), as.Date, "%d %B %Y"))
# [[1]]
# [1] "2013-03-31" "2013-03-31"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "2011-12-01"
lapply(res, format.Date, "%d-%m-%Y") # or "%d-%e-%Y"
# [[1]]
# [1] "31-03-2013" "31-03-2013"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "01-12-2011"
```